# shell scripting grepping for pattern and then echo message

Tags: linux, unix, shell-script, grep

I have a file which has the below pattern

```
=================================================

4601 -- it means completed
4602 -- it means failed
4603 -- it means timed out

=================================================
```

If I do tail -10 to file, then I would get anyone pattern from above.

I want to grep above three number and then display message as Completed|Failed|Timed-Out.

Any Idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a small script that you can use for testing - run it somewhere safe, e.g. /tmp or so:

```
# Prepare
rm *.txt
echo 4601 -- it means completed > f1.txt
echo 4602 -- it means failed > f2.txt
echo 4603 -- it means timed out > f3.txt

# Test
for i in *.txt; do echo
  echo --- Processing file $i
  if grep -qs 4601 $i; then
    echo Completed
  elif grep -qs 4602 $i; then
    echo Failed
  elif grep -qs 4603 $i; then
    echo Timed-Out
  fi
done
```

Thanks @grawity for the helpful tip (see his comment below) for not creating unnecessary subshells / running tests / speeding it up here!

It will create 3 files - f1.txt, f2.txt and f3.txt, each containing one of the coded you mention and then process each of the files, generating the messages you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you icyrock!! it worked...exactly what I neeeded. Cheers!

Comment: `if [ \`grep -c ...\` -gt 0 ]` is unnecessary. `if grep -qs ...` is enough.

Comment: @grawity Thanks, that's a nice tip - edited for others who might stumble upon.